# Is there any specific maximum number of characters within a single page to be considered as good for readability in UX perspective?

Tags: readability, pagination

I am currently researching about readability for a heavy content article that is paginated. I am not sure how to paginate the article because there are no explicit rules that explain how many paragraphs or characters that considered 'too many' in a single page.

Please, could you share some knowledge about it? Thank you

Comment: How many characters there are within a single page of a book?

Comment: Are you after how to lay out the page, rather than the number of characters in the page ? In which case you need to edit your question...

Comment: I believe it should be on the content provider (writer) to determine where a page should start and where it should end. That way it can be logically split into sections and the user doesn't have to worry about switching page halfway between a paragraph or section.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered paginated articles that reloaded the whole page every time I changed the page and it was bad UX, long articles with too much to scroll and no navigation options.

So I would consider making sure that the user can easily navigate to the section he is interested in, be able to search through it and other UX elements.

If pagination is the way to go I would consider these two things: Ease of use, navigation etc. and consider the regular phisical book character count which I found to be:

*" In rough terms, each page of a standard-format hardcover book has about 300-350 words, and each word is five characters plus a space. So a typical book page has, say 1,500 to 1,800 characters (not counting spaces.)."*

https://www.quora.com/How-many-characters-of-text-letters-are-in-an-average-book